# How to use Spannable String in and engine Text?

Tags: android, andengine

i am working on a game using and Engine , now have used HUD to display score , time remaining and Level My problem is i want to use text in two different color like Level 1/10
so Level /10 should be in black and 1 should be in Red color , Is there any way to do that, I used below

```
vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
        back = new Sprite((CAMERA_WIDTH - mBannerTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2,
                0, this.mBannerTextureRegion, vertexBufferObjectManager);

        topBannar = new HUD();

        reset = new ButtonSprite(30, 5, this.mResetTextureRegion,
                this.mResetPressedTextureRegion, this.mResetTextureRegion,
                vertexBufferObjectManager, this);

        topBannar.registerTouchArea(reset);

        back.attachChild(reset);

        levelText = new Text(210, 5, this.mFont, "Level " + stage + "/10",
                new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER),
                vertexBufferObjectManager);

        back.attachChild(levelText);
        scoreText = new Text(375, 5, this.mFont, "Score : " + totalScore,
                new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER),
                vertexBufferObjectManager);
        back.attachChild(scoreText);
        timerWatch = new Text(535, 5, this.mFont, "Time:", 100,
                new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER),
                vertexBufferObjectManager);

        timeHandler = new Timer(1f, StartActivity.this);

        timerWatch.registerUpdateHandler(timeHandler);

        back.attachChild(timerWatch);

        topBannar.attachChild(back);
        camera.setHUD(topBannar);
```

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to do this in AndEngine is to use two separate text objects.

Comment: Thanks,I can use two different text but, It would  not be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `andengine` however if your question is about `spannable` here is a little example.

```
Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString("some string");

//the following code will put the word "string" in bold with yellow background
spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW),
               6, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
               6, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

basically it creates a `spannable` string and then set some custom properties by using `setSpan()`.

I am not sure if this answers your question of if i should remove it because it is off-topic

Comment: Thanks, but i want to use same kind of thing on and Engine Text

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys after a lots of search i found only the way to do that "Use two Text object one preceding the another and set color that you want for them.